# Calculate the memory usage of a HashMap in java

Tags: java, visualvm

I want to calculate the memory usage of two HashMaps in Java and I did these two methods.

1) I use the *visualVM* and I got following result.

**Is it just the size of the Hashmap's pointer not the real amount of memory usage with this Hashmap?**

Because, it just used ''67283648'' bytes.
[image]

2) I run the following code which fill two HashMaps and I got ''576132056'' bytes as a result.

```
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    long memory = runtime.totalMemory()- runtime.freeMemory();
    HashMap<String, TypePosting> typeInvIndex=qpu.loadInvTypeIndex();
    HashMap<Integer,String> map=qpu.loadMapTypeEntityId();
    long memory1 = runtime.totalMemory()- runtime.freeMemory();
    System.out.println(memory1- memory);
```

I just asked this question to be sure that I the second result is the correct value of space usage of these two Hashmaps correctly. Am I correct?

Comment: I would under no circumstances trust #2 as a measurement technique.

Comment: And as far as #1 goes, that's the number of bytes directly taken by node objects in the hash maps, which does not account for the full memory consumption of `HashMap`s generally.

Comment: Louis, I am just curious, which methods of getting runtime instances footprint do you use in Google? Or how YOU will solve this problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the best (precise and easy to implement) way to find java object instance memory footprint at runtime is to use `Instrumentation` interface and implement simple java agent.

It is a common practice, there are plenty of how-tos and code samples in the Web. [Just one example](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074458/core-java/estimating-java-object-sizes-with-instrumentation.html) (which you can use as a starting point)

Answer (score 2):

Please see the [In Java, what is the best way to determine the size of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object). There is a short and nice example of how to measure any java object size.